# Connect access denied while all variables are correct

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Used code for connection

```
<?php 
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
?>
```

current settings:
[image: current settings]

^User name, Host name,  Password,   Global privileges,  User group, Grant^

Error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::16' (using password: NO) in /storage/ssd3/007/15887007/public_html/dbh.php on line 5

I'm using 000webhostapp.com for my website and XAMPP for database

Comment: If you are using a hosting provided database, I would be Very Very surprised if you were allowed to use `root` and also whatever that user account should be, that the password was blank. **Check the hosts documentation**

Comment: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-connect-to-database-using-php/42093?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=859f323cd2ab25b941b96be6d00d05160a7dbe05-1610892867-0-AQQvLc9VVHXLW1W5eLeGyrlg0lkunKjoNEuPsvM1MkJX-IFl46-79K5N83boc5OFJq925_p43VbLpWgq2_AQj0p8xGt3lG068SbBf_PINHLb8BMR74ekX42hQxvB0HrUvgsMXTF3W6BNAY7owmYBchzsn1U2-U0Acsro1z2cAQae5cORrBk8iaoZW0-VoXtlYECo15GNgh4-4gTBFQGlHJKipVX-O2j28bDgj_3ZAHntyGIT3l_MHMRmwjWw2bOZc_JQgS37kyOdO-zuCnl0jtNn5bASJPoQ7xGGOtlDVdcRqETS8F0WIc86KfhuoEQaeFOtfzENhJ_gefQURMJ04mLY8E2qWMdbh5rulg7ci4vG2ztrMrgdcguUtVQT6piwhg

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to make your remote server connect to your local MySQL database? In that case it would seem that your local server doesn't accept root logins from remote connections..

Comment: @RiggsFolly thx, that makes a lot of sense. I made a database at the server and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add database name.

$dbname = 'your db';

Comment: OP seems to be connecting with root account. Why do you think it's not going to work without database name?